# Is it a sin if husband divorce a wife?

Tags: women, talaq, sin

Is it a sin if husband divorces his wife with a reason that she was talking and helping with some information to his male friend and his family ?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know divorcing is not a sin but on the other hand I have heard that divorce is the worse halal. In fact it means although divorce is a halal act but this is counted as the worsts Halals. Therefore I think it is not haram or sin to divorce her but it might be suggested a lot to bear even the hard position as much as possible in order not to divorce (as much as I remember). of course you can do more search about it. wallaho a'lamo.

Comment: please add your  resources to your answer. I suggest you read [How do I write a good answer?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)